# Code-signing does not work since Mavericks

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

since there were changes of code-signing since Mavericks (10.9.5) I am trying to use new version (V2) of code-signing to get our app (Eclipse based) working on Mavericks.

Before the last update to 10.9.5 everything worked well, but since that problems appeared. 
We were code-signing (V1) on 10.7.5 and had to upgrade to Mavericks 10.9.5. 
Developer's ID etc. is correctly installed (as it was before), but still the process does not work.

The command I use:

**security unlock-keychain && codesign -s 'Developer ID Application: OurID' 'OurApp.app'**

I've also tried --deep option or -f, --verbose etc. Nothing works.

I am not really sure what is the problem, the error I get follows:

**OurApp.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: ../OurApp.app/Contents/MacOS/__MACOSX/jre/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator**

If I just for testing purpose remove the folder __MACOSX I get basically the same message:
**OurApp.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: /../OurApp.app/Contents/MacOS/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime**

Does anyone know and could explain me where could be the problem?

OurApp.app is basically unpacked Eclipse.app, our plugins, icons and unpacked JDK.

I was trying to find any clue how to continue, what to fix etc. but could not find anything.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not well versed in the details of this stuff, but I've been casually following a related bug discussion in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445015

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any satisfying solution there, maybe after some time.. :/